# How to show JSON ENCODE data in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, object

I am using `$.getJSON` in a jquery script to get data from a php file.

The JSON data i `get` is :

```
{
    "total_posts":23,
    "schools":[
        {"id":"23","name":"School1"},    
        {"id":"22","name":"School2"},
        {"id":"21","name":"School3"}
    ]
}
```

I am able to display the `school` array in a template (im using underscore) but i want to display the `total_posts` in a normal div. So in this case in the `totalposts` div i want the value from JSON, that is `23`:

```
<div id="totalposts">23</div>
```

What i tried:

```
$.getJSON(url, mygroup, function(data){
    var total = data.total_posts;
    $("#totalposts").html(total);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get an error? Also, are you sure you have a div with the given id in your HTML? Keep in mind that the element might be only availavle after the page has been loaded (use `$(document).ready()` )

Comment: Your code is correct, can you give move details about what is happening ?

https://jsfiddle.net/3ckqo1ov/

Comment: Exactly **HOW** is this not working?

Comment: Maybe #totalpost is not set in DOM. Learn firebug...

Comment: Thank you mates .. After checking everything for the 50th time i found the error. In the DOM I had set the `<div class='totalposts'>` and in the script i was calling for the div id. Thanks again .. Have a nice weekend !!